# Change URL in Pagination in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-router

I have used angular UI-router, I'm trying to change URL in pagination.
UI Bootstrap pagination directive used.

I'm using this one
[github link](https://github.com/rahil471/search-sort-and-pagination-angularjs)

[Demo link](http://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/search-sort-pagination/)

In this pagination working perfect.
But I need to **change url in state** by clicking pagination.

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-if="1 < pages.length">
<li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(1)">&laquo;</a>
</li>

<li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">&lsaquo;</a>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index" ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == \'...\' }">
    <a ui-sref="result.(pageNumber)" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
</li>

<li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">&rsaquo;</a>
</li>

<li ng-if="boundaryLinks"  ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
    <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.last)">&raquo;</a>
</li>
```

in config.route.js

```
.state('result', {
            url: '/result',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/search_result.html'
        })
        .state('result.{pageNumber:[0-9]{1,4}}', {
            url: "/{pageNumber:[0-9]{1,4}}"
        })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out $location , it would help you .It has a method that can change url .

Comment: I just edited with code, 
ui-sref="result.(pageNumber)"
I tried like this but no luck.

Comment: it will be something like this in <a> tag    ui-sref="result({pageNumber: pageNumber})"

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got answer with another guy.

just use the state as below

```
.state('result', {
    url: '/result',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/search_result.html'
})
.state('result.pageNumber', {
    url: '/:pageNumber'
});
```

and pass URL like

```
<a ui-sref="result.pageNumber({pageNumber : pageNumber})">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
```

Tried and got perfect answer.